# Is this a valid z-transform of $ \frac{1}{n^2}u[n] $?

Tags: discrete-signals, z-transform

I was looking over some DSP and came across the following signal: $x[n] = 1/n$. So I wondered whether it had a z-transform but I soon realized that it fails to meet two conditions described [here](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/fp/Existence_Z_Transform.html):

> ...(1) the signal starts at a finite time and (2) it is asymptotically
>   exponentially bounded...

So I modified it to meet those requirements: $x[n] = \frac{1}{n^2} u[n] $

(*I assume $n>0$ is a condition or perhaps $u[n]$ should be changed to $u[n-1]$.*)

Considering that signal, I believe it satisfies both requirements however I don't see anything like it in a table of common z-transforms, but it can be rewritten as:

$ x[n] = \frac{1}{1^2}*\delta[n-1] + \frac{1}{2^2}*\delta[n-2] + \frac{1}{3^2}*\delta[n-3]\ +\  ...$

Which I believe transforms to $ X(z) = \frac{1}{z^1} + \frac{1}{(2z)^2} + \frac{1}{3^2z^3} +\ ...  $

Does this transformation make sense? Is it the best approach? And if it's correct, is there a more compact way to express it?

Comment: The Z-transform of $\frac{1}{n^2} u[n-1]$ is explained in [this answer](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/32207/4298).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've got is definitely the z-transform of that signal (by definition).  For a more compact expression, notice that the [polylogarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polylogarithm.html) is exactly the infinite sum you've shown (just replace $ z \rightarrow 1/z$ in the Mathworld expression). Unfortunately I don't think there's any nicer way to write it; sometimes there just isn't.